# Calling %history from python runtime outside of qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

My desired outcome is to get, similar to what is possible in qtconsole, this type of output:

```
%hist
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame()
```

But for code run in the python runtime.

I have explored `inspect`, `pdb` and `traceback` but they do not give the clean output of only the code in the `__main__` scope.

How would I extract code run in the `__main__` or current (eg: only in one function) scope?

I tried hacking around in `https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/code.py` and doing stuff like:

```
import IPython.core.magics.code as magic_code
c = magic_code.CodeMagics()
c.save(parameter_s='%hist')
```

but to no avail.
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The key to its action is `get` calls to the `self.shell.history_manager`.  I don't know the details about this, but the manager has to be running (in the background) through the session.  In `ipython` session, the manager manages the `In` list and `Out` dict.  The history is derived from those.  In other words, `%history` isn't getting any information from the base Python interpreters; it depends on the `ipython` console.

Comment: @hpaulj okay! let's say I was in a qtconsole or notebook environment. How would I access the current session's history?